# Any performance differences in Spring Security ignoring() versus permitAll()?

Tags: spring-security

It appears both "ignoring()" and "permitAll()" are ways to by-pass Spring Security when requesting a web resource.  What are the performance differences seen from using either approach and why is one faster/scalable then the other?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Eugen Paraschiv](http://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll) on his excellent blog regarding these parts of Spring security the conclusion would be that something like:

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
```

is more efficient than this:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll();
```

simply because the filter(s) involved in the spring security mechanism will be bypassed...